# nanoKontrol2 mapping with Ableton Live 9 - python, pots, cc... - good tutorial?

Tags: midi

I've been trying for a while to get nanoKontrol2 to map one of its pan pots correctly to one of Ableton's channel pan pots (and eventually map the physical pot to an Autofilter parameter instead). The main issue is that the pot jumps when at the 1/2 mark, whether going up or down. Have tried to resolve issue by selecting Value scaling as well as Pickup, from preferences, but problem persists. Am using the Mackiekontrol script, which is the problem (it's the closest contender, but not a real match).

I need to learn how to do this myself. I'm looking for a resource that explains CC in detail and it's relation to other aspects of Midi commands etc. Then, how that fits into Python scripting... and the physical architecture of a pot. I know that's a lot of info to get through but i don't seem to find any scripts that do what i want them to do. Any suggestions totally welcome!!

cheers!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is basically a list question.

Comment: Hi Chaz - if you can edit this to limit it to one specific question we can probably reopen and answer. As it is, Dorito is right - it's waaaay too broad.